# vb.net Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: excel, vb.net, indexing, datagridview

I currently have a datagridview which has an image inserted using the following code;

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"

    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
    End If
    Try
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim img As Byte()
        img = ms.ToArray()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(img)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Once clicking and selecting the image it shows in the datagridview1.

When proceeding and clicking button2 with the following code i obtain the error;

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Save to excel with headers
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
        Next
        For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
            .cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(i).Value
            For j = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
            Next
            Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1")
            formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1", "A1")
            formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue)
            formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1", "A1")
            formatRange.EntireRow.BorderAround()
        Next
    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    '
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
    Application.Exit()
    End
End Sub
```

The form itself has the following code;

```
'  Create Datagridview image column
    Dim dgvImageColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvImageColumn)
    dgvImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
    Dim dgvTextColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Image"


    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

When i click on proceed to save to excel it gives me the following error;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

And the line it refers to is as follows;

```
.cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(i).Value
```

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

Appreciate any support

*IMAGE ADDED TO DATAGRIDVIEW

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"

    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
    End If
    Try
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim img As Byte()
        img = ms.ToArray()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(img)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the debugger, check the value of `i` and how it compares to the various Collections whose index it is.

Comment: `Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(i).Value` - this looks wrong: are you looping diagonally over the datagrid view ?  Does it have at least as many columns as it has rows ?

Comment: @TimWilliams it only has a single row and column but i have used this code for various other projects when needing to export the data from datagridview to an excel workbook.

Comment: If it only has a single column then how would `Cells(i)` work for values other than zero ?  The similar line below inside the `j` loop looks more correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the indexing more complicated than it has to be. Juggling the DIFFERENT row indexes in the `DataGridView` with the different row indexes in excel is complicating things. Try the simplified version below and it should work as expected.

```
With ExcelSheet
  For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
  Next
  Dim excelRowIndex = 2
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
      .cells(excelRowIndex, j + 1) = row.Cells(j).Value
    Next
    excelRowIndex += 1
  Next
  Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1")
  formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1", "A1")
  formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue)
  formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1", "A1")
  formatRange.EntireRow.BorderAround()
End With
```

**Edit to comment for error**

I am confident you are getting this error because of the image/picture you are trying to (incorrectly) insert into an excel worksheet cell with the line below.

```
.cells(excelRowIndex, j + 1) = row.Cells(j).Value
```

First… you cannot add an “Image/Picture” to an excel “Cell”. You can add a shape that has an image into the worksheet. You can also, using the pictures properties have the picture move with respect to a certain cell, however, again… you cannot “directly” add an image to an excel cell as you can with the datagridview. Therefore, the line above will crash if the value in the grids cell is an image.

Second, is possibly a good reason to consider using another excel library, is that unfortunately the Excel interop library does NOT have a method to add a picture/image by passing it an “Image” object (at least that I am aware of). You can add the shape/image from a string path, but if you already have the image (as you do), then you will have to save it to a file in order to pass the image to Excel. This means, that you will have to either save the file as just described, OR keep/save each images cells path. There is a post that demonstrates how to do this using the clipboard and paste to insert the image without having the file path… [How to insert picture from resources to Excel sheet, using VB2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369967/how-to-insert-picture-from-resources-to-excel-sheet-using-vb2010)

Neither approach above seems desirable, unfortunately if you must use interop, then you may have no choice. My understanding is that there are better open source libraries and this issue may be one of the reasons for their existence.

Lastly, whichever library you choose to use, placing the picture shapes is going to need some extra care since as I explained above, you cannot simply add the picture to a worksheet cell as you can with the `DataGridView` cell. This will definitely involve keeping track of where the picture shape is placed in the worksheet making sure it remains visible AND stays with its related data.

The updated code below has an Image column in column 0. When exporting this column, since I am not keeping track of the image paths the user may choose, the code simply outputs the same image. It places the image into the worksheet where: `picX` and `picY` variables define the top left corner of the picture. Each new picture is simply shifted down and to the right by 10 pixels. This is where you would need to apply the logic to tell the shape/picture which cell to stay with if rows are delete etc… . Just a though, hope it helps.

```
With ExcelSheet
  For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
    .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
  Next
  Dim excelRowIndex = 2
  Dim picX = 50
  Dim picY = 50
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
      If (j = 0) Then
        .Shapes.AddPicture("D:\Test\TestImage.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                           Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, picX, picY, 200, 45)
        picX += 10
        picY += 10
      Else
        .cells(excelRowIndex, j + 1) = row.Cells(j).Value
      End If
    Next
    excelRowIndex += 1
  Next
  Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1")
  formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1", "A1")
  formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue)
  formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
  formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1", "A1")
  formatRange.EntireRow.BorderAround()
End With
```

Comment: i get an error: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`The line:.cells(excelRowIndex, j + 1) = row.Cells(j).Value

Comment: rather than specify the location: '`.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Chris Ford\Desktop\", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                           Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, picX, picY, 200, 45)` Is there a way to interlink it with the selection made for the picturebox1? as i can't always define where a user might have a image located.

Comment: Example if possible: `.Shapes.AddPicture("*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                           Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, picX, picY, 200, 45)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the interop method expects a “string” that defines a “path” to a file. Your last comment appears to be trying to merge the open file dialog with the `AddPicture` method and I do not think that will work.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure if I follow your last comment: _”as i can't always define where a user might have a image located”_... if the user selects the image every time the program runs then you can use the path returned from the Open File Dialog. Otherwise, there are several things you can do, One as I said in my answer is to simply save the “Image” (you have) to disk then pass that path to Excel… it will read the image file into excel. Once done, you can delete the image file because Excel will import the whole image not just a link to the image.

Comment: Without fully understanding what you are trying to achieve. I am not following something… when the user picks a picture, and it gets inserted into a data grid view cell… unless you want the user to selected this picture every time the program runs (which is questionable)… you are going to have to SAVE either the file itself or its path. Obviously if you simply save the path, that the USER selects, then there is a very good chance that file may be moved or deleted later and therefore making the path to the file useless.

Comment: “Saving” the file itself into the programs private storage and is hidden to the user, then there will be less chance of it getting moved or deleted and obviously there will be no need to keep a path to the file as you will define this path and the file name. Later, when the program runs again, you will not have to ask the user for this file. I am guessing I may be missing something.

Comment: Hi JohnG.If for example to user wanted to select image1.jpg when using the application the first time then it shouldn't be a problem as I've specified the location. If the user runs the application again and wants to select image2.jpg which is stored in an alternative location ("C:/users/Chris Ford/my documents) how would i go about overcoming this? I just wanted to thank you so much for the assistance you've provided this far!

Comment: Hmm. Well you are going to have to “SAVE” this info/path (as you did with the first one) to use the next time the user runs the program. When the user selects the file, you should have everything you need to save either the path or the file itself for later use. I am missing what this picture represents. If a user changes a picture, do you want to keep only the last selected picture? Or do you want to keep all the pictures the user selects?

Comment: The picture represents a surgery the surgeon has carried out for patient A. When patient B has an operation they will upload a new image and save it to another excel document which is renamed which can be referred to at a later stage for referencing purposes or share the file with colleages for learning and understanding how an operation has been conducted

Comment: From what you describe, it seems clear you need to save the file itself or its path. Once the Excel file is created it is unclear what you want to do with the image files for later use in the `DataGridView` however if the file is not needed in the grid, you could delete the images since a copy is in the excel file. Either way, if you want the picture(s) to be in the grid the next time the program runs then, obviously you will have to “SAVE” this info for each picture.

Comment: Obviously, I am missing something… I would think there would possibly be numerous pictures per patient. I do not want to get off subject, as it appears we have, using the code in my answer are you able to import the pictures as expected? At least as I described, I sympathize with anyone having to work with pictures in Excel or worse yet Word.

Comment: Using your code it does work if i specify the location. If i choose a image that isn't specified then it doesn't work which is what im trying to overcome. As this application would be built and issued to users so i can't specify the location of any given image on their computer. Is there a way to save the location from the datagridview image and incorporate with your code? So when they select it autofills the location part of your code?? Hope i make sense

Comment: Currently, when the program runs, do pictures show up from previous runs? Moreover, if pictures do display from previous runs, then… how are those pictures loaded into the data grid view? I cannot believe the user has to re-select the pictures every time the program runs.

Comment: Hi John, the picture doesn't show up from the previous run unless i select any image which is overwritten by the C:/Users/Chris Ford/Desktop/Capture.Jpg part of the code. Please check my original post at the bottom for selecting the image. The user would need to select a different single picture each time they run as its a bespoke report for each patient. i was hoping to have this code `Shapes.AddPicture(PictureBox1.Image, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse`  making this problem resolved but obviously it isn't accepted. or `Shapes.AddPicture(" ", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTristate.Mso.`

Comment: is there anyway to share my concept with yourself so you understand where im coming from and the outcome desired?

Comment: I am guessing this may link to a chat room [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143836/johng-chat)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Save to excel with headers
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim myOutputFile As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\Image.jpg"
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(myOutputFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
        Next
        Dim excelRowIndex = 2
        Dim picX = 50
        Dim picY = 50
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                If (j = 0) Then
                    .Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Desktop\Image.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                       Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, picX, picY, 200, 200)
                    picX += 10
                    picY += 10
                Else
                    .cells(excelRowIndex, j + 1) = row.Cells(j).Value
                End If
            Next
            excelRowIndex += 1
        Next
        Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
        formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1")
        formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1", "A1")
        formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue)
        formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
        formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1", "A1")
        formatRange.EntireRow.BorderAround()
    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    '
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
    Application.Exit()
    End
End Sub
```

Answered!

Thank you JohnG

Reading upon that thread you shared i used the code `PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`

Very Happy! Thank you for the support and guidance. Its users like you in this community that encourage me to learn and share!